# After Effects: gradient overlay on multiple shape layers

Tags: after-effects, premiere, color-correction

I have a basic animation in After Effects which I want to export in a white version, a black version, and a colored version with a gradient. A frame of the animation is shown here:

[image: Screenshot of composition]

I can link all the fills and strokes of the individual shapes to a Color Control in an adjustment layer and as such easily change the color from black to white, no problem there. However, I am stuck with creating the gradient version of the animation. It is important that the gradient blends well within the different shapes, i.e. all shapes should follow some global gradient so that it seems like it is one shape instead of a collection.

I tried putting a gradient ramp in an adjustment layer and link a gradient fill for a shape to that, but I can't link the colors of a gradient fill to the colors of a gradient ramp. I wondered if there is some solution to this.

What I want is similar to the feature in Photoshop where you can put a gradient above some shape layer and clip it by holding Alt/Option and clicking between the two layers. If there's some way to do this in Premiere Pro by exporting my animation in black and fixing the colors afterward in Premiere, that's sufficient as well.

Is this possible? Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After some trying out, I found a solution that works for me: I can make a new composition containing my existing composition and an adjustment layer and put a Gradient Ramp on the adjustment layer. Works perfectly!